# Windows 8 app live tile not updating on Application App using Visual Studio

Tags: windows-8, notifications, microsoft-metro, winjs

I just created a "Navigation App" project in Visual Studio, and I'm trying to get the live tile to actually update.  This is what I have in my default.js:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  WinJS.Binding.optimizeBindingReferences = true;

  var app = WinJS.Application;
  var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
  var nav = WinJS.Navigation;

  // init notifications to live tile
  var notif = Windows.UI.Notifications;
  var tileUpdater = notif.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication();
  var recurrence = notif.PeriodicUpdateRecurrence.halfHour;
  var updateTileUrl = "http://bakersdozen13.lfchosting.com/img.xml";
  var url = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(updateTileUrl);
  tileUpdater.startPeriodicUpdate(url, recurrence);

  app.addEventListener("activated", function (args) { ... }); // the js that came w/ the project template

  ...

})();
```

When I hit F5 to run it, then check out the tile on my tile Start dashboard Windows 8 screen, it just has my logo in it and nothing else.  What am I missing?  Do I need to put the notification snippet elsewhere?

Ps, this is what the xml is that's getting returned from the update uri:

```
<tile>
  <visual>
    <binding template="TileWideSmallImageAndText03">
      <image id="1" src="http://cdn.godvine.com/uploads/2012/11/image_1353288711_abandoned_church_1.jpg" alt="img alt text here"/>
      <text id="1">Dying Man Gets a Miracle in Abandoned Church</text>
    </binding>
    <binding template="TileSquarePeekImageAndText04">
      <image id="1" src="http://cdn.godvine.com/uploads/2012/11/image_1353288711_abandoned_church_1.jpg" alt="img alt text here"/>
      <text id="1">Dying Man Gets a Miracle in Abandoned Church</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
</tile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine. I tried your URL in the Push and Periodic Notifications Sample in the SDK, and the tile update came through fine, so nothing wrong with the XML. I then did your steps: new Nav app project, pasted in the code, and ran in VS. It took a few seconds for the tile to appear on the start screen, but once it did, the tile update appeared as expected.

In short, this worked fine when I tried it.

You could try putting the code within the activated handler. It is conceivable that there is some race condition between how the app is being deployed by VS and the timing of the tile creation. You could try the Deploy  command on VS's Build menu, which should install the app separately from trying to run it. Then launch it from the tile, and after the app is up, go back and watch the Start screen.

Do note that the wide tile update in your XML will be ignored for a default app project because it has no wide static tile image. That is, you have to include a wide tile image in the manifest for live wide tiles to be enabled, otherwise those parts of the XML payload are ignored.

Comment: how do I deploy it, then run the deploye'd app?  maybe I could try that. I did move the code to w/in the activated handler, to no avail.

Comment: and, "I tried your URL in the Push and Periodic Notifications Sample in the SDK" - what do u mean?  Is this a property you provided in Project settings or something? I would love to just go into the properties, provide a url, frequency, and call it done.

Comment: The sample I referred to is here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Push-and-periodic-de225603. It gives you a working client against which you can test your service. But the app does need to call the WinRT API itself to set up periodic notifications. Running the app from VS should be sufficient, but you probably do want to uninstall manually as Andre suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an app that I developed and deployed with Visual Studio. This app didn't have a live tile at first. When I later added the code for the live tile, the tile didn't update.

My solution was to uninstall the app (via the app bar on the start screen) and to deploy it again. That time everything worked fine without any code modifications.

Comment: I tried that to no avail :/ where did you put the notification code ?